# Make array from a range in D language

Tags: iterator, range, containers, d, phobos

In D language, what is the shortest way to construct an array from a given range?

Let I have an iterator `i`. How to make an array of its elements (in order)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.array` (from [std.array](https://dlang.org/phobos/std_array.html#.array)).

Example:

```
import std.array : array;
import std.range : iota;


int[] arr = 10.iota.array;
```